# Update db record in foreach loop with Entity Framework in asp.net mvc 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I know there are similar questions, but in my case something is wrong. Just trying to update each row, but it does nothing for some reason and no errors.

Thanks.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var db = new DoskaUsContext())
    {
        foreach (var category in db.Categories)
        {
            category.Count = 25;
            db.Categories.Attach(category);
            db.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        db.SaveChanges();

        return View();               
    }
}
```

Comment: The "attach" and "state" lines are not needed because the entity is already attach in this example.

Comment: unfortunately, it is not working

Comment: Are you able to run SQL Profiler to see if/what is hitting the database?

Comment: Sorry, it was my stupid mistake, I forgot to update entity model. Everything works with the code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//3. Mark entity as modified
db.Entry(Category).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;     

//4. out side for loop call SaveChanges
db.SaveChanges();
```

It works.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following, I haven´t tested it yet:

```
public ActionResult Index(Categories category)
    {

        using (var db = new DoskaUsContext())
        {
            foreach (var cat in category)
            {
                category.Count = 25;
                db.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
            return View();               
        }
    }
```